# Psycopg2 issue with double-dollar $$ sign

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have an issue with `$$` in psycopg2 library. For testing purposes I've created simple code snippet like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
AS $$
BEGIN
    select 1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and if I process it in any postgresql client it's all fine, but processing in psycopg causes `unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$...`

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How are you processing it on `psycopg2`? Show the code as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me doing:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres')
proc_sql = """CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
AS $$
BEGIN
    select 1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;"""
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(proc_sql)
con.commit()
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is that I have a bunch of procedures in string and I'm doing ```for q in queries``` and it's parsing line by line.

Comment: Without you adding the code to your question, there is not much anyone can do to come up with a specific solution.